# cell deletion of UITableView and the red sign

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delete-row

I am trying to create a todolist using swift2 . first of all i've created a table and each row in this table is actually an element of an array storing structures with two properties called "title" and "description" it works fine when i try to add a new task to me table but when I want to delete it , I drag it to one side which works fine but no red deletion sign appears so i cant really delete it and when i click else where it -the row- will come back to where it was  here is my code for deletion part

```
 func  tableView (tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete ){
            mgr.tasksArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            TableTask.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

compare the following code to yours:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var content = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return content.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
      self.content.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
      tableView.reloadData()
//      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic) -> the better option in my opinion
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: again it gets swapped but no deleting sign appear

Answer (score 0):

For those of you referring to this question later my mistake was that I had not specified the required constrains so some part of the table were simply out of the screen . 
I hope it has helped you :)